# Confuse of Spring Xml config bean and Annotation config bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Lately I am confused about 1 thing. 
I defined `PlaceHolderConfigurer` in `applicationContext.xml` and config `1 bean` in `applicationContext.xml` too, for example it's called `myService` which has a `property: name` I inject value with `@Value($env{name})`. 
And this bean is also annotated with `@Service` annotation, then I add `<Component-scan.....>` in dispatch-servlet.xml. 
I thought the property: name doesn't get value, `because Xml bean is overridden by component scan bean and`PlaceHolderConfigurer can't be shared between `application context and dispatch servlet context`, but actually it have value which I configured in property file. 
So is there anyone can explain a little bit for me? 
Anything will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you show your applicationContext.xml and your servlet context xml

Comment: There is almost nothing in it, just as I described, and I'm at home, can't connect to my office desktop, so I can share it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You created two versions of one bean - one defined in applicationContext and one in dispatcherServlet. That usually wrong.
2. As you suggest `PlaceHolderConfigurer` not shared beetween parent/child context. It works only for context where it defined.

Comment: ＠Alexander Kudrevatykh, I know that's not a good way, while it works in my project, so I get confused and I know it's not shared between different contexts, Can you explain more about my confusion?